# Find all 2-transitive groups in SAGE

Tags: sage

In GAP I can find all 2-transitive groups from degree 1-31 as follows:

```
2TransitiveGroups := [];
for n in [1..31] do
    Add(2TransitiveGroups, AllTransitiveGroups(DegreeOperation,n,Transitivity,2));
od;
```

I'm struggling to be able to do this in Sage. I can find all transitive groups (from the GAP database) in Sage as follows:

```
G = TransitiveGroups(d)
```

But I don't know how to specify the level of transitivity. I'm sure this must be possible in Sage, as it has GAP's database of transitive groups.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well.  The problem is that probably the easiest way to do this is by just putting your code in GAP via Sage.

```
st = "2TransitiveGroups := []; for n in [1..3] do Add(2TransitiveGroups, AllTransitiveGroups(DegreeOperation,n,Transitivity,2)); od;"
gap.eval(st)
G = gap("2TransitiveGroups")
G
```

This yields `[ [  ], [ S2 ], [  ] ]` but Sage doesn't know what to do with that, as trying `G._sage_()` will show you.

One could try something more sophisticated using GAP commands like

```
sage: G = gap.AllTransitiveGroups("DegreeOperation",2,"Transitivity",2)
sage: H = G.Remove(1)
sage: H
S2
```

But Sage still can't convert this easily to a Sage group for some reason. Ordinarily [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1118284/24113) should tell you how to convert this into a Sage group, but apparently whatever GAP is returning in this list of lists isn't a GAP group somehow.  If you can figure out how to get these GAP commands to give you back a group, then `H.AsPermGroup()` and the question I linked to *should* work.

Comment: Thanks for the response and suggestions. I tried to get GAP to return the proper format but I couldn't get it to work. I ended up parsing each output of TransitveGroups (in Sage) and manually found the correct index (big pain).